# How to assign a value from JSON to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using the CheckPoint API in my web app and I am trying to store the "sid" in a variable.
How can I do this? 
Below is the code snippet that I use to login

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({ user: "Licenta2020", password: "Licenta2020" });

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: "follow",
};
fetch("https://192.168.100.100/web_api/v1.6/login", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

And here is the result of this request, I want to take the sid value and assign to a variable so I can use it later on for other requests.

```
{
  "uid" : "4a587f4b-6a0a-4e0f-a1f4-cb99b19657dd",
  "sid" : "ite95YKJ7gmV-7s4YJbHIeAke9ODoklA5Z1yVHriRkA",
  "url" : "https://192.168.100.100:443/web_api/v1.6",
  "session-timeout" : 600,
  "last-login-was-at" : {
    "posix" : 1591398092564,
    "iso-8601" : "2020-06-06T02:01+0300"
  },
  "disk-space-message" : "Partition /var/log has: 1354 MB of free space and it's lower than required: 2000 MB\n",
  "api-server-version" : "1.6"
}
```

Tried this code snippet too

```
.then((result) => {
    let sid = result.sid;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(sid);
  })
```

Comment: like `let sid = result.sid;` ?? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, but when I do this (I will add the update to the question, when I try to console.log it it shows up as undefined.

Comment: you should do result["sid"]. also instead of response.text() use .json()

Comment: response.text() => response.json()

Comment: Thanks a lot, Avi! You are a legend.

Comment: don't be rude by answering question from someone's comment. instead mark the respective user's answer as correct . so if it helped then mark my answer as correct

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and I don't really know how it works

Comment: no worries. Please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning text in promise as
`.text()`  instead use `.json();`

that's because `.json()` automatically parses to json for you. so after that you
could continue to use`result["sid"]` to get desired output

Comment: You don't need to use ["sid"].  It's not necessary unless you prefer it.  You'd only need to do this if you are using a mangler that requires explicit string key property access to prevent mangling.  Most modern manglers already handle this so it isn't really even necessary for that anymore either.

Comment: that's just fail safe for older versions and other languages. doesn't make much difference in new js versions though

Comment: I don't think there was ever an issue in any browser even as far back as IE5.5 with this.  The only place it was an issue was with Google Closure Compiler Advanced Mode in the early days.

Comment: well i couldn't agree more. but kid is new so using that could help him being lost in json and js objects + spaces in key issues.

Comment: it's more about perspective i agree. yours is by no way wrong.